# Installed Matlab but no executable

Tags: software-installation, matlab

Installed Matlab from their official website (they sent me package), free-trail 30 days, but there is no executable file. I found it in `usr/share/applications` but I couldn't launch. I'm using GNU/Linux 16.04 lts.

Comment: What *exactly* did they send you - and how did you install it?

Comment: Have you already finished C?

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem!
When you run install from terminal, DON'T FORGET to type "sudo ./install " 
 instead of "./install".
That was reason installation couldn't create new folder in usr/local/ , 
which is default. Now I can easily run matlab by typing 'matlab' command in terminal.